# Use all resources for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a problem with one database on SQL Server. I have a database with one table. This table has more than 5 million rows, and I want to run a select query.

When I try to run `SELECT *` on this table, the server completes the task in 3 minutes, and never uses maximum hardware.

The server has the following configuration:

- Server HP
- Ram 32
- CPU 2*8Core
- HDD 500GiG raid 5

I ran a hardware test with Performance Test Software and the server health is good.

I have a question: why does SQL Server not use 100% of hardware to run the query faster?

SQL Server just used 3-5% CPU and 20 meg (per sec) read from hard.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 Data Center edition and Windows Server 2012 r2, all of these are updated.

I ran the query on the server using SSMS and in this case we don't have network and buffering.

My DB size is 1.5 GIG and all my hards are SSD.When i copy file on my hard the speed is 500m/s.

This Table has 20 field and their type is int and Nvarchar.

Comment: Why do you think it's server that takes 3 minutes and not client that fetches the result for 3 minutes? Try to select every field in a variable: select @col1 = col1, ...@colN = colN from yourTable, that will be the time of select, not the time that client fetches the result

Comment: >>>This table has more than 5 million rows<<< And what is the size of this 5mln rows? You can have just 1 integer field in your table and you can have 20 LOB ( varchar(max) ) fields, in last case it's normal to take 3 minutes to retrieve that data

Comment: You must search what is your bottlenek ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_(software) ) You must see wait types for your query.

Comment: from looking at that I'd say your hard disks are your limiting factor, however what are you doing with those 5 million rows, are you selecting them all into SSMS which will take a while to load them in, or are you loading them into a temp table somewhere,, 32 GB of ram isn't a lot to be running SQL Server and an OS on (not to mention anything else) it's also worth noting that SQL will only take the resources that it is set up to use and the OS allows it to use as you cant cripple the OS as that would in tern cripple SQL.

Comment: What's your MAXDOP?  Do you have any resource governor profiles setup that may limit this connection?  What does your definition of "maximum hardware" mean?  Have you performed this query while running a [perfmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx) trace?  If so, can you post those results?

Answer (score 3):

First check the execution plan. I would expect a non-parallel plan for this trivial query so no more than 1 logical CPU will be used. That comes to about 6% total CPU that can be used on your 16 core system if there are no other waits.

Client processing, rendering, and network time for 5M rows is significant and may explain why you're only using 3-5% CPU instead of 6% possible. This will manifest itself as async_network_io waits while SQL Server waits for the client to request the next buffer of data.

Although there may be IO waits as well, I doubt that will be the long pole in the tent here. I'd expect most of the IO for the full scan against a cold cache to be done with async read-ahead reads so CPU will be the bottleneck after client/network time is eliminated. You can test this by running the query directly on the database server from SSMS with the discard query results option.